# How can i change the url link and use it with selenium

Tags: url, selenium

I have some URL like "https://some.url.ru/new-token". I need change it to "http://some.url.ru/new-token" (mean change HTTPS to HTTP). I can't change whole URL, because every time I get new token.
(Selenium, Java).

So, my question:

1. I get the URL: driver.getCurrentUrl();
2. then I need change it - change HTTPS to HTTP: HOW?
3. I need use new URL: HOW?

I found solution:

```
StringBuffer newUrl = new StringBuffer(driver.getCurrentUrl());
newUrl.deleteCharAt(4); //4 - it's number of symbol what should cut, first symbol have number "0"
driver.get(String.valueOf(newUrl)); //there url would be without 5th symbol.
```

So: NOW question still stay one of two: how change "some" to "another" in example?

Comment: Is your question to use url with https security but you would want to get it using http? Your question has a stark violation of web security! Please update the question with proper research that you performed. [check out how-to-ask in SO](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @GirishSortur my question not relevant to security. Sometimes i need change part like "some" to "another" also (in example "https://some.url.ru/new-token").

Comment: do you want to take the url, and change it to http then `.get(url)`. Or change the `href` and send click action?

Answer (score 1):

The java.lang.String class provides a lot of methods to work on string. By the help of these methods, we can perform operations on string such as trimming, concatenating, converting, comparing, replacing strings etc. In your case, for example to replace 'https' with 'http', you can do something like this:

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
String newUrl = url.replace("https", "http");
```

Not sure what the use case is, but if you want to navigate to this new url, then do

```
driver.get(newUrl);
```

Similarly, to change "some" to "another" as you have asked:

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
String newUrl = url.replace("some", "another");
```

Comment: What about if "some" is dynamic: "some" could be "smthelse" when for me important open the url with "another"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.replaceAll()` to change substring like:

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
String url_new = url.replaceAll("string/to/change", "new/string");
driver.navigate().to(new_url);
```